# Dynamically fill form in zf2

Tags: forms, frameworks, zend-framework2

I need to fill "select" option from my database (without using Doctrine) in ZF2 when form is generating.
My form:

```
class RegisterTeacherForm extends Form
{
   ....

    $this->add(array(
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
        'name' => 'RegisterTeacherCountry',
        'attributes' => array(
            'id' => 'country_id',  
            'class' => 'selectable',
            'autocomplete' => 'off',
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'value_options' => array(
                'default' => 'Please Select',
                'Austria' => 'Austria',  //how i do fill this section from DB?
                'France' => 'France',
                'Germany' => 'Germany',
                'Spain' => 'Spain',
            ),
        ),
    ));
}
```

Thanks all for any answer!

Comment: are you using doctrine?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using doctrine, do this:

```
$this->add(array(
        'name' => 'RegisterTeacherCountry',
        'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect',
        'attributes' => array(
            'id' => 'country_id',  
            'class' => 'selectable',
            'autocomplete' => 'off',
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'object_manager' => $this->getEntityManager(),
            'target_class' => 'YOUR ENTITY NAMESPACE',
            'property' => 'your db collumn name',
            'disable_inarray_validator' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'is_method'      => true,
            'find_method'    => array(
                'name'   => 'findBy',
                'params' => array(
                    'criteria' => array(),
                    'orderBy'  => array('nameOfCollumnYouWantToOrderBy' => 'ASC'),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ));
```

Comment: No, i dont using doctrine. Im using native db connect through adapter in zf2

Comment: I think yes, but I'm used native methods

Comment: I am not really used to use native methods, but I guess you could run a query, then, in the controller use `$form->get('RegisterTeacherCountry')->setValueOptions($yourresultsarray);`

Comment: you are welcome! You should choose the answer, or create a new one with your solution to help others!